# Indicator variable for dates within 7 day range of each other in R

Tags: r

I am working with electronic health records data and would like to create an indicator variable called "episode" that joins antibiotic medications that occur within 7 days of each other. Below is a mock dataset and the output that I would like. I program in R.

```
df2=data.frame(
  id = c(01,01,01,01,01,02,02,03,04),
  date = c("2015-01-01 11:00", 
           "2015-01-06 13:29", 
           "2015-01-10 12:46", 
           "2015-01-25 14:45",
           "2015-02-15 13:30",
           "2015-01-01 10:00",
           "2015-05-05 15:20",
           "2015-01-01 15:19",
           "2015-08-01 13:15"),
  abx = c("AMPICILLIN",
          "ERYTHROMYCIN",
          "NEOMYCIN",
          "AMPICILLIN",
          "VANCOMYCIN",
          "VANCOMYCIN",
          "NEOMYCIN",
          "PENICILLIN",
          "ERYTHROMYCIN"));
df2
```

Output desired

```
id            date          abx     episode
1 2015-01-01 11:00   AMPICILLIN     1
1 2015-01-06 13:29 ERYTHROMYCIN     1
1 2015-01-10 12:46     NEOMYCIN     1
1 2015-01-25 14:45   AMPICILLIN     2
1 2015-02-15 13:30   VANCOMYCIN     3
2 2015-01-01 10:00   VANCOMYCIN     1
2 2015-05-05 15:20     NEOMYCIN     1
3 2015-01-01 15:19   PENICILLIN     1
4 2015-08-01 13:15 ERYTHROMYCIN     1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use `ave` like this:

```
grpno <- function(x) cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) >=7 ))
transform(df2, episode = ave(as.numeric(as.Date(date)), id, FUN = grpno))
```

giving:

```
  id             date          abx episode
1  1 2015-01-01 11:00   AMPICILLIN       1
2  1 2015-01-06 13:29 ERYTHROMYCIN       1
3  1 2015-01-10 12:46     NEOMYCIN       1
4  1 2015-01-25 14:45   AMPICILLIN       2
5  1 2015-02-15 13:30   VANCOMYCIN       3
6  2 2015-01-01 10:00   VANCOMYCIN       1
7  2 2015-05-05 15:20     NEOMYCIN       2
8  3 2015-01-01 15:19   PENICILLIN       1
9  4 2015-08-01 13:15 ERYTHROMYCIN       1
```

or with dplyr and `grpno` from above:

```
df2 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(episode = date %>% as.Date %>% as.numeric %>% grpno) %>%
    ungroup
```